# Assign specified numerical value to a vector of strings

Tags: r

Is there a way of creating new vector of numerical values based on my vector of strings?

For example I have this :

```
a<-c("A", "B", "A", "A")
```

and from this `a` I want to make new vector `b` with values replacing "A" with 1 and "B" with -1 so `b(1, -1, 1, 1)`

I tried using something like `factor(a, levels = c("A", "B"), labels = c(1, -1))`
 but this doesn't produce numerical vector.

Comment: `as.numeric(as.character(factor(a, levels = c("A", "B"), labels = c(1, -1))))`

Comment: The `factor` method is good you just have to convert it to numeric the right way [(possible dupe? Converting factor to numeric R-FAQ)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3418128/903061)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Packages
library(stringi)
library(microbenchmark)

# 1. Vector
# a <- c("A", "B", "A", "A") 
a <- stri_rand_strings(1e5, 1, pattern = "[A-B]")

# 2. The 'factor' solution
f1 <- function(){ as.numeric(as.character(factor(a, levels = c("A", "B"), labels = c(1, -1)))) }

# 3. The faster solution
f2 <- function(){ (-1)^(a != "A") }

# 3. Ifelse solution
f3 <- function(){ ifelse(a == "A", 1, -1) }

# 4. Ignore case of letters or my solution
f4 <- function(){ ifelse(as.numeric(grepl("a", a, ignore.case = TRUE)) == 1, 1, -1) }

# 5. Code map solution from "Nathan Werth"
f5 <- function(){ c(A = 1, B = -1)[a] }

# 6. Test
microbenchmark(
  f1(), f2(), f3(), f4(), f5())

Unit: milliseconds
expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
f1() 23.331763 23.648421 28.253174 24.235554 26.582799 123.49315   100  b 
f2()  5.808460  6.025908  6.421053  6.067174  6.200166  12.94342   100 a  
f3() 13.817060 14.926539 25.900652 16.388596 18.122837 129.67193   100  b 
f4() 28.772036 31.363670 39.185333 32.352557 34.388918 134.35915   100   c
f5()  4.577321  5.186689  8.727417  7.375286  7.895280 106.31922   100 a
```

Comment: If you're going to post benchmark code, you should post the results so we can get a sense of relative rankings at least. (And if you're going to benchmark, do it on a big enough vector to matter, at least 1e5 elements.)

Comment: @Gregor I've done test for 1e5 random chars as you suggested me. Please, have a look on the results above

Answer (score 4):

No need to that, just use:

```
a[a=="A"] = 1
a[a=="B"] = -1
a = as.numeric(a)
```

if you want keep a unchanged use:

```
    b = a
    b[a=="A"] = 1
    b[a=="B"] = -1
    b = as.numeric(b)
```

**Or better solution** as @joran said:

```
b = ifelse(a == "A",1,-1)
```

Comment: if i want to keep my `a` unchanged?

Comment: Or just `ifelse(a == "A",1,-1)`.

Comment: @lllook joran solution is better anyway I posted an edit.

Comment: @SirSaleh Feel free to edit my suggestion into your answer as well.

Comment: @joran sure, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
code_map <- c(A = 1, B = -1)
b <- code_map[a]
```